# Joining two tables in Rails ,which was mentioned as has_one: ".. ",class_name:"..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Transport::Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :driver, class_name: "Admin", foreign_key: "driver_id"
end
```

```
Transport::Vehicle.joins(:driver)
```

produces the following SQL query

```
SELECT  "transport_vehicles".* FROM "transport_vehicles" INNER JOIN "admins" ON "admins"."driver_id" = "transport_vehicles"."id" AND "admins"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $1
```

But it should be

```
SELECT  "transport_vehicles".* FROM "transport_vehicles" INNER JOIN "admins" ON "admins"."id" = "transport_vehicles"."id" AND "admins"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $1
```

How can i get admin.id instead of admins.driver_id ??

Comment: In your `admin` table, do you have a `driver_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your foreign key is on the Transport::Vehicle class, you should use *belongs_to* instead of *has_one*.